# Decomposition to maximize square of sums rather than sum of squares like eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix eigenvector decomposition finds the set of orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{v}_i$ that maximizes the norms of those vectors $\mathbf{v}_i^\top\mathbf{v}_i=\lambda_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue. In this sense we maximize the "sum of squares" of each $\mathbf{v}_i$. Is there an alternative approach that instead maximizes the "square of sums" of each $\mathbf{v}_i$?

Comment: By the "square of sums" of a vector $\mathbf x$ do you mean $(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n)^2$?

Comment: Separately, I don't see how the equation $\mathbf{v}_i^\top\mathbf{v}_i=\lambda_i$ ever appears in finding the eigenvector decomposition of a matrix. This doesn't depend on the matrix at all. Also, you can achieve $\mathbf x^\top \mathbf x = \lambda$ starting from any vector $\mathbf x$ just by scaling it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "square of sums." To make the connection to a matrix more clear, I wish to find a set of orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{v}_i$ such that

\begin{align}
\mathbf{C}=\sum_i \mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{v}^\top_i
\end{align}
in a way that maximizes the quantity $\mathbf{d}^\top\mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{v}^\top_i\mathbf{d}$ for each $i$, where $\mathbf{d}=[1,1,1,\dots,1]^\top$ is a vector of ones with the dimension of $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: This decomposition only exists for positive semidefinite matrices, and in most cases it is nearly unique. Even when it's not, the sum of the values you're maximizing is just going to be $\mathbf d^\top \mathbf C \mathbf d$, regardless of the decomposition, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the sum of the values to be minimized is $\mathbf{d}^\top\mathbf{C}\mathbf{d}$. The positive semidefinite restriction is fine, and for my purposes I'm concerned just with symmetric $\mathbf{C}$, the covariance matrix of a real-valued random vector.

Comment: Maybe it's just $\mathbf{v_1}=\mathbf{d}^\top\mathbf{C}$, proceeding iteratively from there (regressing and removing $\mathbf{v}_1$ from $\mathbf{C}$) to get the rest of the $\mathbf{v}_i$?